# Loop resets an element of an array after first iteration?

Tags: c#

As the question mark suggests, I do not understand what is happening and lack the knowledge. In short, I'm trying to create Horner's method as a console application. Here is the code, which is still a bit rough.

```
namespace HornerMethodConsole
{
    class Program
    {     
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Coefficients");
            int[] c = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine($"Choose dividers of {c[c.Length - 1]}:", c);
            int[] a = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

            int sum = c[0];
            int[] sumArr = new int[c.Length];
            sumArr[0] = c[0]; // keep the first coeffiecient
            for (int k = 0; k < a.Length; k++) //for every divider
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < c.Length - 1; i++) //for every coefficient
                {
                    sum = c[i + 1] + (sum * a[k]);
                    sumArr[i+1] = sum;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", sumArr));
                sum = c[0];
            }

            if (sumArr[sumArr.Length - 1] == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The nulls are");
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", sumArr));

                Console.WriteLine("New dividers:");
                int[] b = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

                int newSum = sumArr[0]; 
                Array.Resize(ref sumArr, sumArr.Length - 1);
                for (int m = 0; m < b.Length; m++)
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < sumArr.Length - 1; n++)
                    {
                                              
                          newSum = sumArr[n+1] + (newSum * b[m]);// PROBLEMATIC PART  sumArr[n+1]  
                          
                          sumArr[n + 1] = newSum;                       
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", sumArr));
                    newSum = c[0]; 
                }
                
            }          

        }
    }
}
```

This is the part, which causes the problem.

```
                for (int m = 0; m < b.Length; m++)
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < sumArr.Length - 1; n++)
                    {
                          int sumTest = sumArr[n + 1];  // PROBLEMATIC PART                        
                          newSum = sumArr[n+1] + (newSum * b[m]);
                          
                          sumArr[n + 1] = newSum;                       
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", sumArr));
                    newSum = c[0]; 
                }
```

The first iteration of the main for-loop( the one with the "m" variable) prints out the correct values, but after entering every next iteration the value of sumArr[n+1] reverts to 0.I say it reverts, because that is the only conclusion I could draw after debbuing the code.The input is as follows:

```
1 2 -4 -3
1 -3
1 -3
```

The last two lines of the console that appear currently:

```
1 0 -1
1 -3 8
```

But should be:

```
1 0 -1
1 -4 11
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest a couple of basic things to help: Name your variables more verbosely. For instance, you have a comment that `c` holds Coefficients; why not name the variable `coefficients`?  And so on. Then you can speak more intelligently about what's going on in your code. Combining that with stepping through the code line by line and using the debugging tools to tell what's in each variable, you should gain a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: what is the input for you "New dividers:"? Your both loops are doing same job, how first is working and second is not, there could be some problem with the variables got reassigned and array got resized. It would be helpful to debug if you create all new variables for second loop